# exact equations and integrating factors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When it says ... show that it is an exact equation it means that you have to multiply by $m(x)=\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}$ firstly?

Given the following equation, show that it is an exact equation, afterwards find the solution, if there are any irregular points when $C = 2,$ then draw the graph around these points.

$$\cos(x)\sinh(y)\,dx - \sin(x)\cosh(y)\,dy = 0.$$
(I found $m(x)=\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}$ as  i get ∂/∂ = cos x cosh y and ∂/∂ = −cos x cosh (not equal))

Comment: Please do not post images with the question. You are supposed to at least do the effort of learning how to enter mathematics at this site and type in the question. You are also supposed to  *show your work*: what have you tried, where are you stuck? It's OK to get stuck and ask a question so that you can get unstuck, but it's not OK to ask for your homework to be done for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ODE
$$M(x,y) dx+N(x,y) dy=0~~~(1)$$ is exact i }$$ \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}= \frac{\partial N}{\partial x} ~~~(2).$$
If not, then a factor $\mu(x,y)$ on multiplying the ODE can make it exact, where 
$$\frac{d\ln \mu}{dx}=\frac{\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}}{N} ~~~~(3)$$

For the given equation
$$\cos x~ \sinh y~ dx -\sin x~ \cosh y~ dy=0 ~~~(4)$$ 
$$\frac{d\ln \mu}{dx}=-2 \cot x \Rightarrow \ln \mu=-2\int \cot x  ~ dx \Rightarrow \mu=\csc^2 x.$$ Finally $u=\csc^2 x$ is the integrating factor, which on multiplying (4) will make it exact. Then the new ODE will follow (2) with redefined $M$ and $N$.

The modified ODE is $$M' dx+N' dy=0 \Rightarrow \cot x \csc x \sinh y dx -\csc x \cosh y dy=0~~~~(5)$$. its solution is given as
$$\int M'(x,y)~\mbox{ [treat y as constant]}~dx+ \int \mbox{[terms of N'(x,y) not containing x]}~dy=C.$$ So we have
$$\int \cot x \csc x \sinh y dx+\int 0 dy=C \Rightarrow -csc x \sinh y=C.$$
$$\Rightarrow -\csc x \sinh y = C$$
is the solution of (4) and (5).

Comment: i am really glad for your quick responce ! thank you !

Comment: but i get ∂/∂ = cos x cosh y and ∂/∂ = −cos x cosh

Comment: @George Atana, Sorry I have edited it please see it now.

Answer (score 0):

(,)+(,)=0  is exact if ∂/∂=∂/∂ .
In this case ∂/∂ = cos cosh , ∂/∂ = - cos cosh
So if you multiply by 1/sinx^2 then you get an exact differential equation.